# require_once :failed to open stream error: no such file or directory

Tags: php, require-once

```
$conn = mysql_connect($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());

require_once dirname('../tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once dirname('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

error: Warning: require_once(../tcpdf/config/lang): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\jmb_system\anggerik\printunitstmt.php on line 33

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../tcpdf/config/lang' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\jmb_s

Kindly where is the error? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

dirname() gives you the path of the directory (in this case '../tcpdf/config/lang'). Require_once needs the file. Just remove the dirname().

```
require_once('../tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

or, if the "tcpdf" folder is in the same directory:

```
require_once('./tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

Comment: hi salkin, after i have removed DIRNAME and the error still the same. it still pointing on the require_once line there.

Comment: then the path is wrong. is the 'tcpdf' folder in the same directory than your php script? Then remove the '../' from the path

Comment: is i doesn't have the eng.php and tcpdf.php? then how should i create out the code?

Comment: I assume u have downloaded tcpdf  When you put the "tcpdf" folder at the same place like your php script the code would be "require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');"

Comment: yes i have. is it i need to put the tcpdf file together with my script or how?

Comment: there is a folder called "tcpdf". Put this one in the same directory than your php script, then require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); works.

Comment: and something more: try removing the require_once('./tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php'); (keep only the require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); ) as it seems this file is not included in standard download!

Comment: it's function already according what you have suggested. but the error right now pointing on this line of code "$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);"

Comment: this line seems to be optional. try to remove it.

Comment: OMG. it works so well, thanks for your kind guidance.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/path/to/file";
```

where

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

means current file path.
Very usefull for relative including.
Don't forget the first slash

```
dirname('/../tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
```

Comment: can you give me one of the example?

Comment: For example, if i have two files like parent_dir/AbstractOutputs.php and parent_dir/implementation/DummyOutputs.php then my including would be: require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../AbstractOutputs.php";

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$filename = realpath('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
var_dump($filename);
```

What does it return? If it returns bool(false), the path/file doesn't exist here.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507